# Unloading data from Views with minimal permissions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a newbie to Snowflake. I'm assigned task to make python script that gets data from Snowflake View and copies it to SFTP server. I have barely any permissions on that account (can only view the shared Views).
Now my 2 questions:

1. Can admin grant me permission to creating internal stages without granting me any more permissions? (I want to ask the admin to give me that permission, but he won't be willing to share anything more with me.)
2. Can I use COPY INTO  command on Views? All examples I read on the internet were about Tables and not Views and I'd like to be sure I can copy Views before asking for any permissions.

I apologize if those questions sound silly, but I have no way of testing those myself as I have no permissions on that account and I need to be sure before negotiating anything with admins.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can be granted access to create stages. Details for it are here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html

2. No, you cannot use "Copy into" and load data to views.

Comment: Thank you so much Srinath. One last questions. I cannot copy data to Views, but can I copy data FROM Views to stages so that I could download it locally?

Comment: I do believe you can use `COPY INTO <location>` to get data from views. You can basically copy anything that you can write as a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done. Also, you can look at the following documentation which details about Unload operation : docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-overview.html